# Why can't add new mode for xrandr?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, hdmi, resolution, xorg

```
cvt 1920 1080 120
# 1920x1080 119.93 Hz (CVT) hsync: 139.12 kHz; pclk: 369.50 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_120.00"  369.50  1920 2080 2288 2656  1080 1083 1088 1160 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_120.00"  369.50  1920 2080 2288 2656  1080 1083 1088 1160 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode HDMI-A-1 "1920x1080_120.00"
xrandr: cannot find mode "1920x1080_120.00"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you find solution(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `~/.config/monitors.xml` file and rebooting